# paragraph and tab in equation in latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Every one can help?

I have an equation:

```
                A = B + C + D + E
                  = F + G
                  = K
```

How to do this equation in latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  You should start by reading or googling a basic book on latex:) Try searching this site for `\begin{align*}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math) package and its display-math environments. For the equation at hand, you should probably use an `align*` environment. In the code shown below, the `&` symbols specify the alignment points, and the `\\` directives indicate line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
                A &= B + C + D + E\\
                  &= F + G\\
                  &= K
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: For a multi-line aligned equation with a single equation number, the `amsmath` package provides the `split` environment, to be used inside an `equation` environment.

The recommendation, that you familiarize yourself with the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math) package, still stands. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:23} 
\begin{split}
P_{n-coh1}[i] &= (L_b^*)(L_p^*)(X_{i1})(L_{i1})^2(L_{i0})^{6*4*2+3} \\
              &= (L_b^*)(L_p^*)(X_{i1})(L_{i1})^2(L_{i0})^{6*4*2+3} \\
              &= L_p 
\end{split}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For this i can do it.
But i want to put this equation between equation  like:


\begin{equation}
\label{eq:23}


P_{n-coh1}[i] = (L_b^*)(L_p^*)(X_{i1})(L_{i1})^2(L_{i0})^{6*4*2+3}
                     = (L_b^*)(L_p^*)(X_{i1})(L_{i1})^2(L_{i0})^{6*4*2+3}
                     = L_p
\end{equation}

Comment: @vandungPHAM - I've provided an addendum to show how a `split` environment does what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: @vandungPHAM - glad my answer was useful. Feel to click the 'accept' check mark. ;-)